# You cannot upgrade a plugin that is configured via BuildConfig.groovy, remove the configuration to continue

Tags: grails

```
Plugin [...] is aliased as [...] to the location [...] in grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy.
You cannot upgrade a plugin that is configured via BuildConfig.groovy, remove the configuration to continue.
```

What are steps to fix grails application configuration?

EDIT:
The issue is opposite to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458730/grails-inline-plugins-cannot-upgrade-a-plugin-that-is-configured-via-buildconfi?rq=1) one. I face the issue using inline mode...

Comment: Have you tried to remove the configuration from BuildConfig.groovy?

Comment: do you understand what does this mean?

Comment: message? I guess it means 'remove in-line plugin', a plugin added with `grails.plugin.location.`

Comment: This is what I'm trying to achieve actually... not to waste time build and install each plugin in huge application.

Comment: Well actually you are looking to upgrade the plugin which has been referred from the location directly. I suppose you did a pull for the latest version of the plugin and try to use it. Remove the plugin artifact declaration from the `plugins` section in `BuildConfig` if you already are using its location.

Comment: We use system property switch. When "inline" is defined then grails.plugin.location is used and dependencies are excluded from "plugins" section.

Comment: I'm not trying to upgrade anything. I'm trying to start application in 'inline' mode.